# ItemList in an ItemList not scrolling

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I have a nested ItemList that is made as follows:

```
SafeArea(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Placeholder'),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: itemList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final itemData = itemList[index];
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Text(
                  itemData.text,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I can scroll up and down  when holding the items directly placed in the first list, doing so also moves the items from the nested list. (wanted behavior)

When holding items in the sublist (the one with the builder), nothing moves anywhere.

I want to make so that all items move when any of them are held to scroll, how can I do that?

Is there a way to build a  list without ListView.builder or did I miss some ListView parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `physics` parameter of `Listview` to achive the intended result.

```
SafeArea(
    child: ListView(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), // add this
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Placeholder'),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // and this
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: itemList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final itemData = itemList[index];
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Text(
                    itemData.text,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Now your list should be scrollable.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks a lot. I had no clue abou the physics